# Showing two sets of points from two different fields in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, attribute-table, map-algebra

I made a union of two adjacent shp (points) files with the same theme (Geochemistry) so the resulting attribute table gave duplicated fields, for example: ID, As_ppm, Ag_ppm, Pb_ppm, ... , ID_2, As_ppm_2, Ag_ppm_2, Pb_ppm_2,...
And the elements of the first shp give 'NULL' in the fields of the second shp and vice-versa, As in the screenshot.
[image]
So my goal is to show the combined points for a speciffic element, say Arsenic, so I have tried, without success, expressions like `As_ppm || As_ppm_2` , `As_ppm + As_ppm_2`, `combine(As_ppm ,As_ppm_2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Union (geoprocessing) feature make a "union" of 2 dataset (C = A united to B). 
Probably you are tring to **JOIN** two dataset.

Try this:

1. Go to JOIN settings: (right click -> properties -> Join)
2. Add Vector Join of the second layer (click on "+" green-plus icon) and set these parameters:

   - Join Layer: "the second layer to join"
   - Join field: "ID"
   - Join Target: "ID"

We assume that "ID" is and unambiguous identifier for both the layer's elements.

Answer (score 2):

If the two source layers have the same fields, you could combine them together using the [`merge`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) tool.

Using the data you currently have, you would have to rely on the `coalesce` function to handle the nulls. If the field has a value, it is used. If the field is NULL, then the replacement value is used. For instance, you could replace null by 0:

`coalesce(As_ppm,0) + coalesce(As_ppm_2,0)`

Answer (score 1):

There is also the NNJoin plugin, which does a nearest-neighbor join. Each point in the first layer will have the attributes added to it from the nearest point in the second layer. Similar to [gianfranco di pietro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/140483/gianfranco-di-pietro)'s answer, but without needing a shared, unique identifier.